# how to make sure locks are released with ef core and postgres?

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core

I have a console program that moves Data between two different servers (DatabaseA and DatabaseB).
Database B is a Postgres-Server.
It calls a lot of stored procedures and other raw queries.
I use `ExecuteSqlRaw` a lot.
I also use [NpsqlBulk.EfCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql.Bulk/).
The program uses the same context instance for DatabaseB during the whole run it takes to finish.
Somehow i get locks on some of my tables on DatabaseB that never get released.
This happens always on my table  `mytable_fromdatabase_import`.
The code run on that is the following:

```
    protected override void AddIdsNew()
    {
        var toAdd = IdsNotInDatabaseB();
        var newObjectsToAdd = GetByIds(toAdd).Select(Converter.ConvertAToB);
        DatabaseBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("truncate mytable_fromdatabase_import; ");
      
        var uploader = new NpgsqlBulkUploader(DatabaseBContext);
        uploader.Insert(newObjectsToAdd); // inserts data into mytable_fromdatabase_import

        DatabaseBContext.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("call insert_myTable_from_importTable();");
        
    }
```

After i run it the whole table is not accessable annymore and when i query the locks on the server i can see there is a process holding it.
How can i make sure this process always closes and releases its locks on tables?
I thought ef-core would do that automaticaly.

-----------Edit-----------

I just wanted to add that this is not a temporary problem during the run of the console. When i run this code and it is finished my table is still locked and nothing can access it. My understanding was that the ef-core context would release everything after it is disposed (if by error or by being finished)

Comment: It seems you are missing a `commit`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name i dont open a transaction explicitly so i what should i commit?

Comment: I don't know EF core, but if a table isn't accessible after a TRUNCATE, this clearly means a commit is missing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name hm ok. Could probably it. I will wait for someone to answer with more knowledge on ef core because as i understood i should get errors then from the NpgsqlBulkUploader. For me ExecuteSqlRaw seems a little bit foogy how it is run on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem had nothing to do with ef core but with a wrong configured backupscript. The program is running now with no changes to it and it works fine

Answer (score -1):

For concrete task you need right tools. Probably you have locks when retrieve Ids and also when trying to do not load already imported records. These steps are slow!

I would suggest to use [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) (disclaimer, I'm co-author of this library)
Create two projects with models from different databases:
Source.Model.csproj - install linq2db.SQLServer
Destination.Model.csproj - install linq2db.PostgreSQL
Follow instructions in T4 templates how to generate model from two databases. It is easy and you can ask questions on linq2db`s github site.

I'll post helper class which I've used for transferring tables on my previous project. It additionally uses library [CodeJam](https://github.com/rsdn/CodeJam) for mapping, but in your project, for sure, you can use Automapper.

```
public class DataImporter
{
    private readonly DataConnection _source;
    private readonly DataConnection _destination;

    public DataImporter(DataConnection source, DataConnection destination)
    {
        _source = source;
        _destination = destination;
    }

    private long ImportDataPrepared<TSource, TDest>(IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> projection) where TDest : class
    {
        var destination = _destination.GetTable<TDest>();
        var tableName = destination.TableName;
        var sourceCount = source.Count();
        if (sourceCount == 0)
            return 0;
        
        var currentCount = destination.Count();

        if (currentCount > sourceCount)
            throw new Exception($"'{tableName}' what happened here?.");

        if (currentCount >= sourceCount)
            return 0;
        
        IQueryable<TSource> sourceQuery = source;
        if (currentCount > 0)
            sourceQuery = sourceQuery.Skip(currentCount);

        var projected = sourceQuery.Select(projection);

        var copied =
            _destination.BulkCopy(
                new BulkCopyOptions
                {
                    BulkCopyType = BulkCopyType.MultipleRows,
                    RowsCopiedCallback = (obj) => RowsCopiedCallback(obj, currentCount, sourceCount, tableName)
                }, projected);
        return copied.RowsCopied;
    }

    private void RowsCopiedCallback(BulkCopyRowsCopied obj, int currentRows, int totalRows, string tableName)
    {
        var percent = (currentRows + obj.RowsCopied) / (double)totalRows * 100;
        Console.WriteLine($"Copied {percent:N2}% \tto {tableName}");
    }


    public class ImporterHelper<TSource>
    {
        private readonly DataImporter _improrter;
        private readonly IOrderedQueryable<TSource> _sourceQuery;

        public ImporterHelper(DataImporter improrter, IOrderedQueryable<TSource> sourceQuery)
        {
            _improrter = improrter;
            _sourceQuery = sourceQuery;
        }
        
        public long To<TDest>() where TDest : class
        {
            var mapperBuilder = new MapperBuilder<TSource, TDest>();
            return _improrter.ImportDataPrepared(_sourceQuery, mapperBuilder.GetMapper().GetMapperExpressionEx());
        }
        
        public long To<TDest>(Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> projection) where TDest : class
        {
            return _improrter.ImportDataPrepared(_sourceQuery, projection);
        }
    }
    
    public ImporterHelper<TSource> ImprortData<TSource>(IOrderedQueryable<TSource> source)
    {
        return new ImporterHelper<TSource>(this, source);
    }
}
```

So begin transferring. Note that I have used `OrderBy/ThenBy` to specify Id order to do not import already transferred records - important order fields should be Unique Key combination. So this sample is reentrant and can be re-run again when connection is lost.

```
var sourceBuilder = new LinqToDbConnectionOptionsBuilder();
sourceBuilder.UseSqlServer(SourceConnectionString);

var destinationBuilder = new LinqToDbConnectionOptionsBuilder();
destinationBuilder.UsePostgreSQL(DestinationConnectionString);


using (var source = new DataConnection(sourceBuilder.Build()))
using (var destination = new DataConnection(destinationBuilder.Build()))
{
    var dataImporter = new DataImporter(source, destination);

    dataImporter.ImprortData(source.GetTable<Source.Model.FirstTable>()
       .OrderBy(e => e.Id1)
       .ThenBy(e => e.Id2))
            .To<Dest.Model.FirstTable>();

    dataImporter.ImprortData(source.GetTable<Source.Model.SecondTable>().OrderBy(e => e.Id))
            .To<Dest.Model.SecondTable>();
}
```

For sure boring part with `OrderBy` can be generated automatically, but this will explode this already not a short answer.

Also play with BulkCopyOptions. Native Npgsql COPY may fail and Multi-Line variant should be used.

Comment: that doesnt answer my question at all and seems to me you just use it to advertise your library. my question was not how to transfer data faster or which tools to use but how to make sure to release locks on the database.

Comment: I want to show you easy way to transfer a million records without locks. I'm sure that IdsNotInDatabaseB() - is a problem. Also try to do that not in transaction.
I don't want to advertise my library it is already popular among people who know SQL.

Comment: IdsNotInDatabaseB should not be the problem it retrives just hashsets of ids. Its just a very simple select to a hashset

Comment: Does this operation in transaction? Anyway it is also can be a problem of `Npgsql.Bulk`. We have discovered earlier in our library that COPY is very sensitive to binary format and it fails on some types.